# How to rewrite "id" url-parameter on a Joomla installation?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, url-rewriting

We have accidentally sent out a number of emails to customers with incorrectly formatted links. In particular, a URL parameter was named "id" where it should have been "ri".
I'm having a hard time setting up a rewrite rule that handles these links and takes customers to the correct place anyway. It seems that Joomla is always "snatching" up the "id" parameter before my Rewrite rules apply and misinterprets it, thus leading to unnecessary 404 errors.

This should in theory work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([slg][^&]+)
RewriteRule ^([den]{2}/)?product/(.*)$ $1product/$2?ri=%1 [L,R=301]
```

In fact, when I replace the "id=" with something like "xyz=" then it does indeed work. However, no such luck with "id".

I have SEF-links and rewrites enabled in Joomla. The above rule is in the `.htaccess` file in the root folder (which also contains the Joomla default rewriting rules). Joomla-version is 2.5.14 .  What do I have to do to make this work?

Comment: Show, please, the SEF link, need work with it in rewrite rules

Comment: The incoming link might look like this: `http://myhost/product/area?id=sABC123` and I need it redirected to `http://myhost/product/area?ri=sABC123`  (in case you're wondering: the bit with the `([den]{2}/)` at the beginning is just a workaround for a limitation of the l10n-extension we chose - should probably have left that out as it isn't relevant to the question, really).

Answer (score 1):

THere is no way for joomla to take action before the .htaccess

If you have that condition at as the first one, I would remove the L Parameter, because it can keep Joomla from building its own rewrite rule.

If you want to check, if the condition is met, simply write a rewriteRule http://www.google.com [L], to check if, the ID= Parameter is really identified

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions

- I would advice adding `QSA` flag. This will keep both `id` and `ri`parameters in resulting URL and then let different codes take whatever parameter they want
- Make this rule as **first rule**
- Test in a different browser to avoid 301 caching issues

Suggested rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=([slg][^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([den]{2}/)?product/(.*)$ $1product/$2?ri=%1 [NC,QSA,NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry, but I definitely do not want the "id"-parameter to be kept. This is exactly what is throwing Joomla off, presumably because it's already using its own parameter named "id" for something else. I just don't understand what mechanism it is using to jump in there even before the root `.htaccess` kicks in...

Comment: OK can you try removing QSA flag from the rule.

Comment: Doesn't work. According to the rewrite.log the rule never triggers, which to me means the condition isn't met. If I change the "id" in the condition to something else then it does work (both my and your version of the rule). Looks to me like Joomla somehow pops the "id" parameter from the query string before it even hits the rewrite engine...